# Split and Contain inside clause where in complex linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, split, contains

I have this linq query, that is doing a select with loads of joins, the query has to return this, and I need to check a "splitted" string for a certain other string. My query is the following:

```
    ....

where 
 && Name.Split(',').Contains(container) == true                                        
                                        ))
    select new
                                         {
                                             ... 
                                         });
```

But this gives me an exception, because of the split method. What can I do? I tried the Any clause, but still gives me an error...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well this doesn't look right to start with `Split(',').ToString()`, also Dont hide error message from people trying to help you. Also this is a big nasty query, its hard to work out what you a trying to do or why

Comment: I had a diff version than the one I started out with. Already editted to it's original syntax. The error is because split is not an recognized method to put in a linq query cause it can't be translated to sql. I thought it was clear for everyone as it's a "rule" for linq, you can't call methods and functions inside a linq query cause it cannot translate it to sql, therefore throwing an exception.

Comment: Replace `Name.Split(',').Contains(container)` with `(Name == container || Name.StartsWith(container+",") || Name.EndsWith(","+container) || Name.Contains(","+container+",")`